# Acceder a sitio en localhost

Tags: linux, centos, servidor, localhost

Al acceder a mi localhost en un equipo con CentOS 7 desde otro equipo si puedo acceder mediante la IP, pero no me carga la pagina completa por que en el código los enlaces dicen localhost y al hacer clic en algún enlace ya no me dirige a la siguiente pagina al no encontrarla.

Hay alguna forma de que al acceder desde otro equipo se interprete el localhost del código como la IP del servidor o alguna forma de visualizar correctamente la pagina?

[image: Las referencias dirigen al localhost, y si accedo desde otro equipo no puedo visualizar los elementos]

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera.

Comment: Por otra parte para resolver tu problema debes cambiar todos los `localhost` de tus enlaces por la ip o el dominio de tu ordenador para que funcione desde otros equipos. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En vez de utilizar rutas absolutas utilizando localhost deberias utilizar rutas relativas.
[Aqui](https://www.discoduroderoer.es/rutas-relativas-y-absolutas/) tienes una explicacion sobre la diferencia que seguro que te ayuda.